# Can't upgrade Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS to fix Heartbleed - Errors with nagios-nrpe-server and bind9

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, heartbleed

an anyone help? I am trying to upgrade but a get error messages about nagios-nrpe-server and bind.

Here is the console output:

```
>apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up nagios-nrpe-server (2.12-5ubuntu1.2) ...
invoke-rc.d: initscript nagios-nrpe-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing nagios-nrpe-server (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up bind9 (1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.8) ...
* Starting domain name service... bind9 [fail]                                                                   
invoke-rc.d: initscript bind9, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing bind9 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
nagios-nrpe-server
bind9
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is a live web server with several hundred domains hosted so I am very nervous about doing anything that will take it out. I have nightly backups but it's a real pain getting my hosting company to restore and can take several hours, so I'm really nervous taking risks.

TIA.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with OpenSSL or Heartbleed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install just the fixes, with `apt-get install -y --only-upgrade openssl libssl1.0.0`

Failing that, you'll need to actually fix your packages, go and look for the apt logs why they are failing, and amend your post with those.